# How to get response from an api, but not a 504 gateway time out issue

Tags: mongodb, graphql

```
module.exports.usersPagination = (root, { start, limit }) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
var status = true;
db.User.find({accountType:'user',isDeleted: {$ne: 
{status}}}).count().exec((err, count) => {
db.User.find({accountType:'user',isDeleted: {$ne: 
{status}}}).sort({created:-1}).skip(start).limit(limit).exec((err, user) => 
{
if(user)
{
 user[0].count = count
 err ? reject(err) : resolve(user);       
 }
 })
 });
 });
 };
```

I've collection of records ie 80,000 and i want to display as 20-20 each page in UI , but my issue is when i'm trying to give start value as "30000"
 in postman it shows bad gateway time out, please help me out.
thanks in advance [image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is due to the fact that the server is taking too long to process the request and return the response:

> 504 Gateway Timeout: The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server. *(from Wikipedia)*

Indeed, your code is performing the query to the database twice:

1. it is true that the second execution is skipping `start` rows, but...
2. ...the first instance of the query is materializing the whole set of rows from the database.

Just query it once and do not materialize the full set of rows.

Comment: I want to show the total users of collection count , so i'm using that first instance of the query

Comment: Got a solution , at the second execution i removed the `sort({created:-1})`and its working fine for me